# C - K&R expr: evaluate a reverse Polish expression from the command line

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

I've been trying to complete exercise 5-10 from K&R using a dynamically allocated stack. I based my code on the code from chapter 4 (they used global variables to implement the stack). The problem is that my programme doesn't work at all and I can't figure out what is wrong. Here's the code:

```
/* expr: evaluates a reverse Polish expression from the command line */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXOP 100 /* maximal operator length */
#define NUMBER '0' /* signal that a number was found */

int getop(char *argv);
void push(double **top, double val);
double pop(double **top);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     if (argc == 1) {
        printf("usage: evaluate a reverse Polish expression from the command line\n");
    return 1;
}

double *stack = malloc((argc-1)*sizeof(double));

if (stack == NULL) {
    printf("error: couldn't allocate enough space for the stack\n");
    return 2;
}

int i, type;
double op1, op2, *top = stack; /* top points to the next free stack position */
char s[MAXOP];

for (i = 1; argv[i] != NULL; i++) {
    type = getop(argv[i]);
    switch (type) {
        case NUMBER :
            push(&top, atof(argv[i]));
            break;
        case '+' :
            op2 = pop(&top);
            op1 = pop(&top);
            push(&top, op1+op2);
            break;
        case '-' :
            break;
        case '*' :
            break;
        case '/' :
            break;
        case '%' :
            break;
        default :
            printf("error: unknown command %s\n", argv[i]);
            return 3;
            break;
    }
}
printf(" = %.8g\n", pop(&top));
free(stack);
return 0;
}

 int getop(char *argv)
{
int i, c;

if (!isdigit(argv[0]))
    return argv[0];
else
    return NUMBER;
}

void push(double **top, double val)
 {
    **top = val;
    (*top)++;
/* is error checking needed? */
}

double pop(double **top)
{
   (*top)--;
    return *(*top+1);
/* is error checking needed? */
}
```

It seems not to take operators into account - for example input ./expr 1 12 13 + + produces output 13.

EDIT:
Thanks for all the help guys, it turns out that push and pop didn't work properly. I've managed to fix that code, although now from the hindsight I see that I could've prepared better before writing the code.

Here is the code after the changes:

```
/* expr: evaluates a reverse Polish expression from the command line */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXOP 100 /* maximal operator length */
#define NUMBER '0' /* signal that a number was found */

int getop(char *argv);
void push(double **top, double val);
double pop(double **top);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     if (argc == 1) {
        printf("usage: evaluate a reverse Polish expression from the command line\n");
    return 1;
}

double *stack = (double*) malloc((argc-1)*sizeof(double));

if (stack == NULL) {
    printf("error: couldn't allocate enough space for the stack\n");
    return 2;
}

int i, type;
double op1, op2, *top = stack; /* top points to the next free stack position */
char s[MAXOP];

for (i = 1; argv[i] != NULL; i++) {
    type = getop(argv[i]);
    switch (type) {
        case NUMBER :
            push(&top, atof(argv[i]));
            break;
        case '+' :
            op2 = pop(&top);
            op1 = pop(&top);
            push(&top, op1+op2);
            break;
        case '-' :
            op2 = pop(&top);
            op1 = pop(&top);
            push(&top, op1-op2);
            break;
        case 'x' :
            op2 = pop(&top);
            op1 = pop(&top);
            push(&top, op1*op2);
            break;
        case '/' :
        op2 = pop(&top);
            op1 = pop(&top);
        if (op2 != 0)
                push(&top, op1/op2);
        else {
        printf("error: division by zero\n");
                return 3;
        }
            break;
        default :
            printf("error: unknown command %s\n", argv[i]);
            return 4;
            break;
    }
}
printf(" = %.8g\n", pop(&top));
free(stack);
return 0;
}

 int getop(char *argv)
{
int i, c;

if (!isdigit(argv[0]))
    return argv[0];
else
    return NUMBER;
}

void push(double **top, double val)
 {
    **top = val;
    (*top)++;
}

double pop(double **top)
{
    double temp = *(*(top)-1);
    (*top)--;
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: May be  this could help you : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/42537/command-line-reverse-polish-calculator

Comment: Your `push` and `pop` are a mess, and that's probably the reason. The `26` is there on the stack.

Comment: also this would be a good time to learn to use a debugger.

Comment: The C tag refers to standard C which is C11 from 2011. Add a more specific tag if you use non-standard C. Note that K&R-C is outdated since 28 years and should never be used for learning or new code (old code should be rewritten whenever possible). If you mean C89/90 (outdated since 18 years), use the corresponding tag. Well meant advice: Get a more recent book about modern C, i.e. C99 at least, better C11.

Comment: You push to the top of the stack, then increment the pointer. Yet you also pop the top of the stack. However, the last value pushed is actually the one before top.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. Now I feel that I should've done more reaserch on stacks in general and prepare myself better before starting to code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to not understand that you allocated an array with `malloc`, and you're trying to use the "add to front" method that is used with pointer-based stacks. You should be pushing new values after the most recent item pushed onto the stack and popping the item most recently pushed onto the stack (i.e. at the "end" of the stack).

The following should work for you. Note that `pcount` is a pointer to the number of items on the stack, else you won't know whether the stack is empty (e.g. `2 +` would be invalid input because `+` requires 2 values but there's only 1 on the stack) or even where to add another value because you won't be able to determine where the "end" of the stack is.

```
#include <math.h>    // for HUGE_VAL; may need to link the math library?

// Push a value onto the stack and update the number of items on the stack.
void push(double *stk, double value, int *pcount)
{
    // Add new values at the end of the stack (technically after the last item pushed).
    stk[*pcount] = value;
    ++*pcount;
}

// Pop a value off the stack and update the number of items remaining on the
// stack. If there are no values, HUGE_VAL is returned. Since it is possibly
// a valid value on some implementations, checking for an error should be done
// using the value pcount points to:
//
//     n = pop(stk, &stkCount);
//     if (stkCount < 0) {
//         // error: stack had no elements before pop
//     }
//
double pop(double *stk, int *pcount)
{
    if (*pcount >= 0) {
        // Remove items from the end of the stack.
        --*pcount;
        return stk[*pcount];
    }
    return HUGE_VAL;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As @AnttiHaapala pointed out, your push and pop are a mess.  Also, your data is organized in a way that makes error checking difficult, if not impossible.

Here are correct push and pops.

```
typedef struct
{
   double* base;    // base address of stack, allocated with malloc.
   double* end;     // top address of stack + 1 double, init to base + number of elements
   double* ptr;     // stack pointer, initialize to equal base
} stack;

int init_Stack(struct stack* p, int items)
{
    p->base = malloc(items * sizeof(double));
    if (!p->base)
        return -1;
    p->end = p->base + items;
    p->ptr = p->base;
    return 0;
}

void push(struct stack* p, double val)
{
    if (p->ptr >= p->end)
    {
        //stack overflow!
        exit(3);
    }
    *(p->ptr++) = val;
}

double pop(struct stack* p)
{
    if (p->ptr <= p->base)
    {
        // stack underflow!
        exit(4);
    }
    return *(--(p->ptr));
}
```